# migration from Google Gitkit to Firebase sdk

Tags: python, ios, google-app-engine, authentication, firebase

Our Mobile app (IOS & Android) uses Google Identity Toolkit (Gitkit) for auth with the following flow:

- Mobile User auths to Google, Facebook or UN/PW using gitkit client
- Gitkit returns its jw-token to our app
- The app then makes an API request sending that JWToken to our backend
- Our app-engine backend (Python) converts the JWT payload into a dict/hashmap describing the user
- We generate our own "app-login-token" for this user
- We store the user & token to the following NDB entities (User, UserToken,
  Unique)
- We return the userID and our app-token to the mobile client
- The app then uses the user/token pair for all subsequent API requests

My question:  How much would we have to change or rewrite in order to migrate to Googles new "Firebase auth"?  Can we keep most of this existing infrastructure or does Firebase require a different approach?

Comment: Firebase already include Google/FB Sign in now so you might just use them ?

Comment: yes...we hope to use them;  what I'm asking is if the process flow and JWToken stuff works the same with Firebase

Comment: I am facing the same, they have now a migration instruction page:
https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/migrate-firebase
But for me the main risk is that all users will get logged out and they will have to login back to the app. Did you find anything on that front?